# Saving all the bar graphs for a dataset in pdf from R

Tags: r, pdf, for-loop, ggplot2

I am using following program for saving all the barplot for a given dataset in pdf, my dataset only has categorical variables,

```
somePDFPath = "C:/Users/manusharma5/Documents/Rtest/graph.pdf"
pdf(file=somePDFPath)  

for (colname in colnames(data2)) 
  {
  par(mfrow = c(2,1))
  ggplot(data=data2, aes(x=colname))+geom_bar()+geom_text(stat='count',aes(label=..count..),vjust=-1)+
  ggtitle(colname)+theme(plot.title = element_text(color="red", size=14, face="bold.italic")) 
  } 
dev.off()
```

I am not able to open the pdf file, its saying there are no pages in the pdf, probably because my program is not able to produce the graphs for respective columns.

Please help me to identify the mistake I made. I appreciate all the help

And also How can I save more than 1 graph in 1 pdf page, so it will save me from 50 pdf page for 50  cat variables

Comment: We need to print `print(ggplot(...))`

Comment: I tried doing print also, but it didn't work

Comment: I think you need `aes_string` instead of `aes`, as we are passing a variable from the loop.

Comment: Thank You, so much It really worked, can you also please help me with, how can I save more than 1 graph in just 1 pdf page